# How to get Prime and Generator value from dhparam.pem?

Tags: c#, .net, pem, diffie-hellman

I use command in openssl to create a dhparam.pem.

```
    openssl dhparam -outform PEM 2048 -out dhparam.pem
```

I need to calculate A = g^a mod p. With g is generator value and p is prime value from dhparam.pem file.

I am using C#, so How do I get value of g and p from dhparam.pem ?

Here is example of dhparam.pem

```
    -----BEGIN DH PARAMETERS-----
    MIIBCAKCAQEAwJuVT+cebJvz0CSiOrdTA41St5XU+NcmE6decZxTcs449IO7rv4U
    Tts07i8RMqWQbDpqB7al9TU68QPDvG/0AzLfz9otzafS8GFr3WAsEt76oYB35j+m
    mwXlLorcA6RtZyq5mmoXLOxy03uGB/mXcWNvHjrps8nDcH439/TDlu4ZHKVxuEkc
    zWHssdqBMSNK0cMPnS1p8ECmnf6qNeP0gIRkLKrMTeY9vf7G0mR2phnyqGsFvgNy
    MSpa6X8vxJM0NzQ2uYyXqfFcXqEjIVQYoDSTaoeGvoNRIrzJc2xu0r2U7QjPHzVV
    6WA4yCfVE+M9Xgjyt/5cjYKz1CyE51+gcwIBAg==
    -----END DH PARAMETERS-----
```

Comment: Maybe you can use something like [AsnEncodedDataCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.asnencodeddatacollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The collection should contain 2 [AsnEncodedData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.asnencodeddata%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) where the first one is the p and the second one is g.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback